# p-dropdown selection with FormControl.patchValue - always selects the first value

Tags: angular, primeng

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xknudv?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

I'm binding the value of a dropdown selection to a `FormControl`. To simplify client-server communication, I want to bind the `id` to the `p-dropdown` model and not the whole selection object.
When I programmatically try to change the value of the selection, it doesn't matter what value I patch, the first value is being selected. In the example above, clicking "Choose Two" chooses "One" instead of "Two".
Manual selection works as expected, of course.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked your stackblitz, and not sure why, but the dataKey is messing it up.

Remove dataKey attribute and your code should be fine.

The issue is not only when you set via the button click. It also appears when you initialize control with the value.

```
formControl = new FormControl(2)
```

It is always picking up the first element irrespective of the value you pass to the control.